# R: Find the character position of where 2 strings differentiate

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I am looking for a way to find if a concatenated string in one dataframe is the exact same in another - if it is not found or different, then I want to return the position of where the strings differentiate.

Example:

DF 1

```
Store      Good  Price   concatenated <br>
1          Apple    1.50   1Apple1.50 <br>
3          Banana   3.50  3Banana3.50 <br>
5          Turkey   6.25  5Turkey6.25 <br>
```

DF 2

```
Store     Good      Price  concatenated <br>
1         Apple     1.80    1Apple1.80 <br>
2         Banana    3.50    2Banana3.50 <br>
5         Turkey    6.25    5Turkey6.25 <br>
```

So I want to return:

For Apple, return 9, because "1Apple1.50 and 1Apple1.80" differentiate at the 9th position of the string 
For Banana, return 1 because "3Banana3.50 and 2Banana2.50" differentiate at the 1st position of the string 
For Turkey, don't return anything because the strings match

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we can split the string with `strsplit` and do a comparison on the corresponding `list` elements and get the position of the first non-match with `which`

```
mapply(function(x, y) which(x != y)[1], 
     strsplit(df1$concatenated, ""), strsplit(df2$concatenated, ""))
#[1]  9  1 NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Store = c(1L, 3L, 5L), Good = c("Apple", "Banana", 
"Turkey"), Price = c(1.5, 3.5, 6.25), concatenated = c("1Apple1.50", 
"3Banana3.50", "5Turkey6.25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Store = c(1L, 2L, 5L), Good = c("Apple", "Banana", 
"Turkey"), Price = c(1.8, 3.5, 6.25), concatenated = c("1Apple1.80", 
"2Banana3.50", "5Turkey6.25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution using `bitwXor` + `utf8ToInt`

```
> mapply(function(x,y) which(bitwXor(utf8ToInt(x),utf8ToInt(y))>0), df1$concatenated,df2$concatenated)
$`1Apple1.50`
[1] 9

$`3Banana3.50`
[1] 1

$`5Turkey6.25`
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some benchmarks of the various approaches suggested so far on 1000 strings of length 1000.  A variation of Akrun's approach that relies on `charToRaw()` instead of `strsplit()` seems to be the quickest.

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr         min          lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 strsplit   38.626212   38.868298   42.48461   42.43953   45.87118   46.32892    10  a 
 distance 6437.995304 6783.890225 6968.59793 7016.14651 7184.29213 7319.84097    10   b
  bitwXor   12.065822   12.278691   17.32897   18.52006   19.95079   26.90822    10  a 
    toRaw    4.572742    4.693785    7.76573    4.87048   10.73064   18.74406    10  a
```

Code to  reproduce:

```
set.seed(5)
size <- 1000
cvec <-  replicate(size, paste0(sample(letters, size, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
cvec2 <- sapply(cvec, function(x)  `substring<-`(x, {y <- sample(size, 1)}, y, sample(letters, 1)))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  strsplit  = mapply(function(x, y) which(x != y)[1],
                     strsplit(cvec, ""), strsplit(cvec2, "")),
  distance = {res <- mapply(function(x, y)
    grepRaw(diag(attr(adist(x, y, counts = TRUE), "trafos")), pattern = "S|D|I"),
    cvec,
    cvec2, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  res[lengths(res) == 0] <- NA
  unlist(res)},
  bitwXor = {res <- mapply(function(x,y) which(bitwXor(utf8ToInt(x),utf8ToInt(y))>0), cvec,cvec2, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  res[lengths(res) == 0] <- NA
  unlist(res)},
  toRaw = mapply(function(x, y) which(charToRaw(x) != charToRaw(y))[1],
                 cvec, cvec2, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
  times = 10, check = "equal")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `base R` option could be:

```
mapply(function(x, y)
      grepRaw(diag(attr(adist(x, y, counts = TRUE), "trafos")), pattern = "S|D|I"),
      df1$concatenated,
      df2$concatenated)

$`1Apple1.50`
[1] 9

$`3Banana3.50`
[1] 1

$`5Turkey6.25`
integer(0)
```

Here it returns the position of where a character was substituted, deleted or inserted, based on Levenshtein distance.

If there could be multiple changes:

```
mapply(function(x, y) 
 grepRaw(diag(attr(adist(x, y, counts = TRUE), "trafos")), pattern = "S|D|I", all = TRUE),
 df1$concatenated,
 df2$concatenated)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to compare two data frames like that directly, i.e. using [`all.equal()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/all_equal.html)

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list(Store = c(1L, 3L, 5L), Good = c("Apple", "Banana","Turkey"), Price = c(1.5, 3.5, 6.25), concatenated = c("1Apple1.50","3Banana3.50", "5Turkey6.25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))    
df2 <- structure(list(Store = c(1L, 2L, 5L), Good = c("Apple", "Banana","Turkey"), Price = c(1.8, 3.5, 6.25), concatenated = c("1Apple1.80", "2Banana3.50", "5Turkey6.25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))

# By default, ordering of rows and columns ignored
# But those can be overridden if desired
# By default all_equal is sensitive to variable differences
# But you can request dplyr convert similar types

all.equal(df1, df2, ignore_col_order = FALSE, ignore_row_order = FALSE)

[1] "Component “Store”: Mean relative difference: 0.3333333" "Component “Price”: Mean relative difference: 0.2"      
[3] "Component “concatenated”: 2 string mismatches"
```